# Removing Entire record based on duplicate values in a specific field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is the query I am using:

```
Select count(DLOCATION), DLOCATION, DPOSTAL
FROM BURNABYFINAL
Group by DLOCATION, DPOSTAL
order by count(dlocation) desc;
```

I would like to remove the entire record that has duplicate "Dpostal" in it.  I have tried using the distinct function but it results in an error due to the group by function. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have added an image. I would only like to keep the record with the highest "count(location)".  The other occurrences should be deleted.

[The duplicate postal code value example is highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf3ho.png)

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the post, let me know if you need any other information

Answer (score 1):

Rank rows by counts, and use it for the final result.

- lines #1 - 11 represent sample data (I was lazy to type everything)
- lines #12 - 17 represent that *ranking* I was talking about
- lines #18 onward fetch the final result by filtering out everything that's not ranked as #1

---

```
SQL> with burnabyfinal (dlocation, dpostal) as
  2    (select '3935 Kincaid St Burnaby', 'V5G 2X6' from dual union all
  3     select '3935 Kincaid St Burnaby', 'V5G 2X6' from dual union all
  4     select '3935 Kincaid St Burnaby', 'V5G 2X6' from dual union all
  5     select '1111 Dont want'         , 'V5G 2X6' from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select '203 Sunset'             , 'A4F 2CS' from dual union all
  8     --
  9     select '200 Hastings'           , 'V92 S9V' from dual union all
 10     select '300 Hastings 2nd'       , 'V92 S9V' from dual
 11    ),
 12  temp as
 13    (select count(dlocation) cnt, dlocation, dpostal,
 14       dense_rank() over (partition by dpostal order by count(*) desc) rnk
 15     from burnabyfinal
 16     group by dlocation, dpostal
 17    )
 18  select cnt, dlocation, dpostal
 19  from temp
 20  where rnk = 1
 21  order by cnt desc;

       CNT DLOCATION               DPOSTAL
---------- ----------------------- -------
         3 3935 Kincaid St Burnaby V5G 2X6
         1 300 Hastings 2nd        V92 S9V
         1 200 Hastings            V92 S9V
         1 203 Sunset              A4F 2CS

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can avoid manually inputting all of these street addresses? I have thousands of records to go through.

Comment: As I said: these lines represent sample data. You have it already, stored in some table. If you posted CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO those rows, I wouldn't have to do it myself. Query you need begins at line #12.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I am a SQL beginner and don't understand most of these functions. I assume this is not a great question but... I pasted lines 12-17 into the worksheet and it worked great! However, I am not sure how to run the second select function.  If I paste lines 12 -21 it returns an error message. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should be `with temp as (select count ... blabla ... where rnk = 1 order by cnt desc`

Comment: I have noticed that postal codes with the same count and rank are still shown (ie.very similar records).  Is there a way to sum the count of the same ranked postal codes? @littlefoot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RANK` function as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(CNT_DLOCATION), DLOCATION, DPOSTAL
FROM
(Select count(DLOCATION) CNT_DLOCATION, DLOCATION, DPOSTAL, 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DPOSTAL ORDER BY count(DLOCATION) DESC NULLS LAST) AS RNK
FROM BURNABYFINAL
Group by DLOCATION, DPOSTAL)
WHERE RNK = 1
GROUP BY DLOCATION, DPOSTAL
order by CNT_DLOCATION desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have noticed that postal codes with the same count and rank are still shown (ie.very similar records).  Is there a way to sum the count of the same ranked postal codes?

Comment: Yes, you can use group by on outer query. I.e. after rnk = 1, use group by 2 columns except count column from select list and instead of count column use sum of that column

Comment: I followed your advice but it did not run. I only changed line 1 to - SELECT sum(CNT_DLOCATION), DLOCATION, DPOSTAL. Added a Line 8 in between the WHERE statement and the order by - group by dlocation, dpostal. Where did I go wrong?